# Problem with access an local Image (not in app workspace) from a local HTML file (in app workspace)

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, air, adobe

I have a HTML box and load a local html file from the project. 
In this HTML file I use jquery and I want to load an image from my user directory.
I see the image from my user directory but jquery doesn't works.
I get this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at crop/onLoaded()[/Flex Bundle/workspace/crop/src/crop.mxml:119]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.html::HTMLLoader/onCompleteTimer()
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

But if I load an image from the app workspace, everything works fine (I see the image and Jquery works).

Is this a policy problem? The error says that is a "null object reference" problem, but this can't be true...

Any ideas?

Damian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Solution for copying a file from the application directory to a self defined directory:

Vars:

```
private var fileName:String = 'config.xml';
private var workingDirectory:String = 'MyNewAppDir';
```

1. Short and simple:

> ```
> var f:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(this.fileName );
> f.copyTo( File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath(this.workingDirectory+"/"+this.fileName));
> ```

OR 2. Long and complicated:

```
/**
 * read content
 */
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath( this.fileName );
var read:FileStream = new FileStream();
read.open(file, FileMode.READ);
var content:String = read.readMultiByte( read.bytesAvailable, "utf-8") ;
read.close();

/**
 * save content
 */
var write:FileStream = new FileStream();
write.open( File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath( this.workingDirectory + "/" + this.fileName ), FileMode.WRITE );
write.writeMultiByte( content, "utf-8" );
write.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does is help at all if you put the image in another directory?

You could put the image file in My Documents/myairapp or /home/user/Documents/myairapp then open it with:

```
var original = air.File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myairapp/test.jpg");
```

You could have a permission problem depending on the directory where the file is?

Comment: That doesn't work. I open the html file and the image from documentsDirectory. i save the new image in the same directory. this works without any permission problems.